# Linux: WGET - scheme missing using -i option

Tags: linux, bash, wget

I am trying to download multiple files from yahoo finance using wget.

To do that i used a python script to generate a text file with all urls that i need.
When downloading a single file (a csv file) using the following code:

```
wget ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=BIOM3.SA&a=00&b=5&c=1900&d=04&e=21&f=2013&g=d&ignore=.csv
```

everything goes OK!
However, when the option -i is added and instead of reading the url directly, but instead reading it from the file, i get the error:

```
Invalid URL ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=BIOM3.SA&a=00&b=5&c=1900&d=04&e=21&f=2013&g=d&ignore=.csv: Scheme missing
```

The file that contains the urls is a text file with a single url in each line. The urls are exactly like the one in the first example, but with some different parameters.

Is there a way to correct this?

Thanks a lot for reading!!

Comment: Yes... put `http://` or `https://` in front of the URLs in your input file

Comment: Thanks! It worked!I realized that in the first example there are some '&' symbols all over the link, which would cause the bash to start processes in the background, so the intended result would not be achieved. To correct that i just had to add "".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve the problem I added double-quotes on the links and a web protocol. For example:

`"http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=BIOM3.SA&a=00&b=5&c=1900&d=04&e=21&f=2013&g=d&ignore=.csv"`

Comment: In my case after removing the "https://" it worked for the link https://static.fsf.org/nosvn/FSF30-video/FSF_30_720p.webm. This was tested on cygwin.